# jQuery FullCalendar Date Storage Problem (RFC-822)

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, fullcalendar, rfc822

Is there a way to have the date that [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) stores into the DB in a date or datetime format, or some other time format instead of varchar, so I can do a sort by date SQL call?

Right now it's being stored as `Mon Jun 13 2011 12:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` which is impossible to sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date as you wish and send it to DB. For example if you have only whole-day-events you can add a date prototype:

```
    Date.prototype.toYMD = function() {
       var year, month, day;
       year = String(this.getFullYear());
       month = String(this.getMonth() + 1);
       if (month.length == 1) {
           month = "0" + month;
       }
       day = String(this.getDate());
       if (day.length == 1) {
           day = "0" + day;
       }
       return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    };
```

you can convert your date to MySQL-formatted one using:

```
    var strID = j.toYMD();
    alert("strID: "+strID);
```

If you need hour, minutes and secs you can extend the above example.
cheers Kris